# Probability Density Function - Possible Values to produce a valid PDF

Tags: probability

The question is :

$f(t) = \frac{5z}{16x}t^2 + z\frac{x-y}{4x}t$  ($x,y,t \in \mathbb{R}$) $(0 < t < 2)$

Express $z$ in term of $x$ and $y$, given $ t$ a random continuous variable?

What are the possible values of $z, x, y$ to produce a valid PDF?

Comment: Well, to begin, you should state what are the properties that define a valid PDF, and how you might express this as requirements on x,y,z.

Comment: Thanks Graham, f(t) is provided as a function of probability density of a product life in market, and t is monthly term, which is also a continuous variable. I was banging my head to the wall to understand the first question..

My strategy is to integrate f(t), and solve it with one, but I am getting to nowhere.

Comment: That is one property. There are others.   Also if the argument, $t$, is the product life, then is its support the entirety of the Reals?

Comment: Thanks Graham, it is of real value, in months term, but definitely values. May I ask where could I find the guideline in solving questions like this. I have been looking around for Shaum practice book.

Comment: Thanks Graham, I know how to solve now, t cannot be entirely of reals!